# Google Cloud Storage - JSON API - Native PHP

Tags: google-cloud-platform

My company has a legacy website written in native PHP, ie, not using a framework like Zend/Codeigniter or Laravel.

I wish to upload images from this application to Google Cloud Storage, using the JSON API.

However, all of the example I see require that the libraries are installed using Composer.

It is possible to install and use this library manually (ie not with Composer)?

If not, is it possible to use Composer in a non-frameworked application such as mine.

Regards

James

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use any framework for your application. You can directly use composer with non-framework application.

Just install composer and run below command to install Google Cloud libraries. 
composer require google/cloud